# Why does RestController expose all the operations in CrudRepository?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-restcontroller

**Setup**

I have a PagingAndSortingRepository from which I want to expose only a limited set of (mostly) read operations and add some of non-DB services. I added a REST controller to front the crud repository.

**Problem**

On Swagger interface, I see all the operations enabled, even if only one operation is called from the rest repo. All the operations get the same path ,e.g. "/rest/foo" in below example.

*How can I disable Spring Boot injecting all the operations?*

**Additional Observations** :

- If I do not have any method using crud repo in the rest controller, operations are not listed. Even though if the crud repo is auto wired.
- I did not want to disable each operation in CRUD Repo individually. Even if I do that Swagger would list the operations, but calls would fail with 405.

**Sample Code**

```
public interface MyCRUDRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Foo, FooPK> {
}
```

---

```
@RestController
public class MyRESTController {

  @Autowired
  MyCRUDRepository repository;

  @RequestMapping("/rest/foo")
  public Foo find(String id) {
    return repository.findOne(id);
  }
}
```

Comment: Define @ApiOperation with the appropriate HTTP Method (GET?) above your find method and swagger will read it and you should get only one entry in swagger-ui.

Comment: @mrkernelpanic thanks. Adding APIOperations suppressed the Swagger listing of implicit operations. I also had to add the "method" attribute in RequestMapping, barring which all the requests, including POSTs were gonig to "findOne" method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two changes I made to fix the issue :

1. Added a method attribute (GET) in RequestMapping. Without this all the methods were allowed, bound to the same method.
2. As suggested by @mrkernelpanic, adding @ApiOperation to the method rectified the error where Swagger added all the methods to it's reported API.